# High torque timing belt

Tags: mechanical-engineering, motors, gears, pulleys, timing

I'm building an automatic litter box for my kitty and I tried building two versions using a GT2 timing belt + pulley but the belt seems to slip from the pulley often (since it requires high torque) and once the belt snapped.

Do you have any recommendations for a higher torque timing belt and a corresponding pulley + tensioner I could buy? I am currently looking into a timing belt for a car + a tensioner + pulley, but perhaps that's overkill. It is pretty cheap though.

More generally, I am also open to suggestions to linear movement without a timing belt, but I'd like the solution to be relatively cheap (under $100 for 2ft of movement)

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe what you're doing is over designed. A litter tray + litter + cat mess shouldn't weigh that much.

Comment: why not a chain instead of a belt?  Timing belts are relatively high speed low power.  Chains are great for low speed - this sounds more like a conveyor than a cam drive.

Comment: maybe you are buying low quality belts

Comment: Maybe you don't have sufficient tension on the belt.